# DMA data loss when changing PWM frequency during the DMA reading

Tags: c, stm32, dma, stm32f4, data-loss

[image]First time working with DMA here and I'm getting data loss when the frequency of a PWM signal is varied during the DMA reading. The DMA request is triggered by a 16MHz clock. I'm using DMA2 on STM32f429zi.

The DMA direction is peripheral to memory, where I try to read the whole GPIO port E to memory. The data loss is clearly visible in the beginning of the DMA reading when the PWM frequency is changed. If I comment out the code with the varying of PWM frequency (see part of the code below), there is no visible data loss in the DMA reading.

You can see in the attached image that the upper plot loses data points of the sine wave (4 points per period) and in the lower plot there is no data loss.

As I understand, DMA should work independently and not be affected by CPU, but for me it seems to not be the case. Could this be due to working with a too high clock frequency? Or am I missing something else? I'm really stuck on this problem, any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Linda

```c
/*------------------- Comment out when not changing PWM frequency --------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//  /* Start 40 MHz */
//  TIM3->CCR1 = 1; // 40 MHz
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* Start DMA for ping signal with length BUFFER_SIZE (PA9 (channel 2) is clockout+ of ADC, sampling on falling edge of PA9) */

if (HAL_DMA_Start_IT(htim1.hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_CC2], (uint32_t)&(GPIOF->IDR), (uint32_t)&aDST_Buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) != HAL_OK)
{
 /* Transfer Error */
 Error_Handler();
}

/*------------------- Comment out when not changing PWM frequency --------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//  /* Continue while timer is lower than 1,3 us */
//  while (__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim5) - timer_val1 < 13)
//  {
//  }
//  /* Start ping, 4 MHz */
//  TIM3->ARR = 20; // period
//  TIM3->CCR1 = 9;  // pulse
//  timer_val1 = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim5);
//  while (__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim5) - timer_val1 < 9) // 5 pulses
//  {
//  }
//
//  TIM3->ARR = 1;  // 40Mhz
//  TIM3->CCR1 = 1;
//  while (__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim5) - timer_val1 < 25)
//  {
//  }

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to properly format your code.

Comment: What do you want to achive with your code? If seems like you want to read back a PWM (duty cycle) via GPIO inputs (Timer output connected to port E?). What is the ADC doing in comment line 5? Please explain you intention a bit more.

Comment: The intention is that DMA should read a sine wave signal sent from an ADC to the GPIO port. In the meantime (when reading DMA stream) should a PWM signal just be sent out for another use.

Comment: You are generally correct, DMA's theoretically operate independently from the main processor. However, they do both share the same data-bus, and I'm assuming your 2 processes (GPIO read, PWM write) may be affecting the same system and causing issues with the hardware you're measuring. I'd suggest first checking to make sure that the data you're attempting to plot above, actually exists in the hardware, and the issue is with the DMA itself -- put an oscilloscope on the bus, and rerun the code, verify if the same output is coming through on both

Comment: What is the original PWM frequency (the frequency programmed before setting up that DMA transfer)? I think there could be some sampling rate problems trying to sample the 40MHz signal with a 16MHz clock. Try changing the code to output a constant 4MHz PWM and look at the graph, then try a constant 40MHz PWM and see if the graphs are ok.